# Load Json Data using Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata, cloudera

I am trying to extract data from below mention json format by pig using `jsonLoader()`:

```
{"Partition":"10","Key":"618897","Properties2":[{"K":"A","T":"String","V":"M "}, {"K":"B","T":"String","V":"N"}, {"K":"D","T":"String","V":"O"}]}
{"Partition":"11","Key":"618900","Properties2":[{"K":"A","T":"String","V":"W”"},{"K":"B","T":"String","V":"X"}, {"K":"C","T":"String","V":"Y"},{"K":"D","T":"String","V":"Z"}]}
```

Right now I am able to extract data from “partition” ,“key” and “V” for every array objects with the following code:

```
A= LOAD '/home/hduser/abc.jon' Using JsonLoader('Partition:chararray,Key:chararray,Properties2:{(K:chararray,T:chararray,V:chararray)},Timestamp:chararray');
B= foreach A generate $0,$1,BagToString(Properties2.V,'\t') as vl:chararray; 
store B into './Result/outPut2';
```

From above code I am getting "Properties2" array value on the sequence basis not column basis, it is creating problem whenever sequence changed or new object comes in existence.
Please  help me to extract data on the basis of column( K values.)

My Output
[image]

Expected Output
[image]

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here

1.Use [elephant-bird](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird) which will give you a map of key and value.

```
A = LOAD '/apps/pig/json_sample' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE json#'Partition',json#'Key',json#'Properties2';
dump B;
```

will give you an output of :

```
(10,618897,{([T#String,K#A,V#M ]),([T#String,K#B,V#N]),([T#String,K#D,V#O])})
(11,618900,{([T#String,K#A,V#W”]),([T#String,K#B,V#X]),([T#String,K#C,V#Y]),([T#String,K#D,V#Z])})
```

Or you have to write a custom loader which has to do this

a).It should know what is the correct order of values that will be coming
for the key **K**

b).Go through each of these values and see if the json is missing any of this key and return an empty/null char for that location.

Am posting the getNext() method of the CustomJsonLoader which will do the same:

```
@Override
public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        boolean notDone = in.nextKeyValue();
        if (!notDone) {
            return null;
        }
        Text value = (Text) in.getCurrentValue();
        List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (value != null) {

            String jsonString = value.toString();
            System.out.println(jsonString);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("obj is "+obj);
            if (obj != null) {
                String partition = (String) obj.get("Partition");
                String key = (String) obj.get("Key");
                valueList.add(partition);
                valueList.add(key);
                JSONArray innArr = (JSONArray) obj.get("Properties2");
                char[] innKeys = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
                Map<String,String> keyMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                for (Object innObj : innArr) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) innObj;
                    keyMap.put(jsonObj.get("K")+"",jsonObj.get("V")+"");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < innKeys.length; i++) {
                    char ch = innKeys[i];
                    if (keyMap.containsKey(ch+"")) {
                        valueList.add(keyMap.get(ch+""));
                    }else{
                        valueList.add("");
                    }

                }
                Tuple t = tupleFactory.newTuple(valueList);
                return t;
            }
        }

        return null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

and register it and run  :

```
REGISTER udf/CustomJsonLoader.jar
A = LOAD '/apps/pig/json_sample' USING CustomJsonLoader();
DUMP A;
(10,618897,M,N,,O)
(11,618900,W,X,Y,Z)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for you time and effort, I tried with elephant-bird I got the same result that have posted but couldn't get values on the basis of column(basis of K value). 
I am quite new in pig and udf part is bit difficult for me can you  please help me out with the prerequisites for customjsonLoader, like jar and code.

Comment: http://arunxjacob.blogspot.in/2010/12/writing-custom-pig-loader.html this is a very easy blog which i followed initially for creating custom loader. Writing udf/loader/store functions for pig is easy if you know java.

Comment: Thanks for response, I went through the blog that you suggested and with the help of your given I prepared custom loader but it is not working When I am executing my pig script it through following error:
 ERROR 1070: Could not resolve Custome using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
 at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:196)
 at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1676)
 at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1409)
.....

Comment: it looks like your udf registration is failing. Make sure the class file is extending LoadFunc and the jar file is available in the path you are mentioning while registration.

Comment: yes I have extended my class  from LoadFunc class and my jar file is also in right path, I think something wrong with my code, can you please check my code, I cant post it here because of text limit.

Comment: can you share the command used for registering, your package and class name and the command used for using the udf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70558/discussion-between-vikram-singh-chandel-and-sonic).